# MySQL Left Join Multiple Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have an interesting challenge... I have two tables, `products` and `users`.

`products` contains 2 columns, `user_id` and `current_bidder`, which hold two different IDs from the `users` table.

I would like to select all columns from `products`, and the name and rating from the `users` table for each `user_id` and `current_bidder`.

Essentially, I'm trying select columns from two different rows on a joined table, while disambiguating their names.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Join to the user table twice, and give each copy a different alias. Something like this:

```
select p.name, p.weight, owner.name, bidder.name
from   product p
join   user owner
on     ...
join   user bidder
on     ...
```

Comment: is more clear `select p.blah as pblah, q.blah as qblah` as OP is asking also desambiguating

Comment: Good suggestion, @LuisSiquot. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

The nice way to avoid ambiguity between columns is to add an `ALIAS` on it.

```
SELECT  a.*,                   -- selects all records from products
        b.name AS user_name,   -- user_name is an alias of  users.name (user_id)
        c.name AS bidder_name  -- user_name is an alias of  users.name (current_bidder)
FROM    products a
        LEFT JOIN users b
            ON a.user_id = b.id
        LEFT JOIN users c
            ON a.current_bidder = c.id
```

The reason why I used `LEFT JOIN` is because I assumed that some products has no `bidder` yet. If `INNER JOIN` was used, product will never be shown on the result until there's a bidder on it.